# How to run multiple service calls in parallel using CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I am returning following response to the user

```
class FinalResponseDTO {
    List<Service1ResponseDTO> service1ResponseDTO;
    Long totalCount;
    List<Service2ResponseDTO> service2ResponseDTO;
}
```

As of now I am making three sequential calls to compute this `FinalResponseDTO`, each of this call can be run independent of others. I tried making three different `CompletableFuture` as:

```
CompletableFuture<List<Service1ResponseDTO> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service1.callMethod1());
CompletableFuture<Long> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service2.callMethod2());
CompletableFuture<Service2ResponseDTO> future3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service3.callMethod3());
```

If I do `CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3).join();` or Should I call `CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3).get();`? Even If I call either of these `join` or `get` then how should I construct `FinalResponseDTO` from it. I am new to the Java 8 concurrency features such as `CompletableFuture` and I am confused, as each return type of each of these future is different, how should I get combined responses of all such futures and then construct my final output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Javadocs of [`CompletableFuture.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf(java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...)):

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete. If any of the given CompletableFutures complete exceptionally, then the returned CompletableFuture also does so, with a CompletionException holding this exception as its cause. Otherwise, the results, if any, of the given CompletableFutures are not reflected in the returned CompletableFuture, **but may be obtained by inspecting them individually**.

So when the combining CompletableFuture completes, you can inspect the values and construct the final response object using a simple constructor by applying a function that constructs the object:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3).thenApply(v -> 
    new FinalResponseDTO(future1.join(), future2.join(), future3.join())
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that for having the List<Service1ResponseDTO> type again you have to get it: future1.get() otherwise it will of the type: CompletableFuture<List<Service1ResponseDTO>

Answer (score 2):

```
    CompletableFuture<List<Service1ResponseDTO> future1 = 
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service1.callMethod1());
    CompletableFuture<Long> future2 = 
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service2.callMethod2());
    CompletableFuture<List<Service2ResponseDTO>> future3 = 
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service3.callMethod3());

    CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3).get();

    return new FinalResponseDTO(future1.join(), future2.join(), future3.join());
```

Note: `supplyAsync` runs on `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` so it would be a good choice to provide your own **executor** e.g. `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> action, executor);
```

Comment: This blocks the caller. Putting your `join()` statements into a `thenApply` allows you to preserve the “pipe”.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `CompletableFuture.allOf`, you could fall back to the somewhat hidden Applicative of the `CompletableFuture`:

```
static <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> alsoApply(CompletableFuture<T> future,     CompletableFuture<Function<T, R>> f) {
    return f.thenCompose(future::thenApply);
}
```

With this helper function you can execute futures in parallel threads:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = alsoApply(
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "a"),
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "b")
.thenApply(b -> a -> a + b));

assertEquals("ab", future.get());
```

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724490/completablefuture-is-a-monad-but-where-is-the-applicative) for where this is coming from and why and how it works.